# Replacing a fixed-position character field using Perl or sed

Tags: regex, perl, ksh

I need to replace a particular range of characters in each line of a file.

I tried this

```
    perl -i -pe 'r77,79c/XXX/g' file
```

I am trying to change the 77th to 79th characters to `XXX` using Perl, but above code is not working.

Comment: do you want replacement for every line in file, or for the whole file?

Comment: Did you *really* think `r77,79c/XXX/g` was valid Perl?

Comment: Actually i want to search a pattern in a file and whatever lines matching that pattern needs to be replaced to 50th & 51st character to XX.

Comment: What?! That is a whole different question. It also isn't very clear. I suggest you write a new question and *give examples* if you find it difficult to express exactly what you need. Something like `perl -pe 'substr($_,49,2)="XX" if /pattern/'` perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -i -pe 's/.{76}\K.../XXX/' file
```

Comment: Don't you need the `s` modifier?

Comment: @Kenosis: This is being applied to *each line* in the file, so unless there are data lines shorter than 79 characters, and the newline should be overwritten if so, then `/s` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

you want to replace chars at position [77-79] with XXX?

try

```
 perl -i -piorig_* -e "substr($_,76,3)=XXX" file
```

a backup file called orig_file will be created cause of preventing possible dataloss..

Comment: This is how I would do it, but the *"77th to 79th"* characters are more likely to be `substr($_,76,3)`. Using `substr` as an l-value is often overlooked.

Comment: @Kenosis' comment on another question has indicated to me that this method will remove the trailing newline if the record is shorter than 79 characters (excluding the newline). It may well be that this never occurs, but you *may* have to `chomp` first and then `print $_, "\n"` after the fixup.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

`Actually i want to search a pattern in a file and whatever lines matching that pattern needs to be replaced to 50th & 51st character to XX`

Using sed:

```
sed -r '/pattern/s/^(.{49})..(.*)$/\1XX\2/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed "/pattern/ s/^\(.\{49\}\)../\1XX/" YourFile
```

we don't touch the end